# bash add backslash before every space?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

if I have text like

```
/mnt/data/web/web content/page 1/home page.txt
```

I get my text with the following command that is then piped to another command.

```
cat somefile.txt | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9=$10=""; print $0}'
```

I need to pipe the above command into another command to add the back slashes

How can I add a back slash before every space so I get correct *nix paths

ie.

```
/mnt/data/web/web\ content/page\ 1/home\ page.txt
```

the text could theoretically be infinitely long but I always need a backslash before every space.
Final script is to be used in freebsd & linux

thanks!

Comment: You can put quotes around the path, then you don't need to escape spaces. e.g. `rm /mnt/data/web/web content/page 1/home page.txt` will fail, but `rm "/mnt/data/web/web content/page 1/home page.txt"` will probably do what you want

Comment: My text is being pulled using cat and an awk statement in a bunch of pipes how can I easily add quotes around the output? here is the relevant part                                                       cat somefile.txt | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9=$10=""; print $0}'  that output is then piped for more data to be added

Comment: I answered...Doesn't work?

Comment: try my awk solution and let me know

Comment: I did what you wanted with `sed command`

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here? If you're quoting your content to be eval'd in a shell script, this isn't the right way to do it (there are legal filenames with more interesting content than spaces).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,"\\ ")}8' file
/mnt/data/web/web\ content/page\ 1/home\ page.txt
```

Comment: may I ask what does  the '8' in the end do?

Comment: It does the same as `1`.  Any positive number would be a true test. If  test is true, do default action, `print $0`.  So it just prints all lines.

Answer (score 2):

Is it useful for you?

```
echo "/mnt/data/web/web content/page 1/home page.txt" > input.txt
```

then:

```
sed 's/ \+/\\ /g' input.txt > output.txt
```

then:

```
cat output.txt
/mnt/data/web/web\ content/page\ 1/home\ page.txt
```

If you want do that for all spaces you can try `awk`

with `awk`:

```
awk -F" " '{ print $1"\\ " $2"\\ " $3"\\ " $4}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: updated my question to add the command im using to get the text if i pipe my command into sed 's| |\\ |' I get a \ at the beginning of each line not before the spaces

Comment: try with awk solution

Comment: Thanks but I need to be able to pipe the input in and pipe it out I am unable to create files on the system. Also the input could have infinite spaces, so I need a solution that will add a \ before every space not after field one, two, three, unless it can do it after every field without typing an infinite number of $1"\\ " $2"\\ "...

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s/\\&/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your entire path:

```
# Create file
echo Hi > "a file  with   spaces"

# Try to cat it
n="a file  with   spaces"
cat $n
cat: a: No such file or directory
cat: file: No such file or directory
cat: with: No such file or directory
cat: spaces: No such file or directory


# With quotes this time :-)
cat "$n"
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Wrap file path with "" so it can be treated as $1
# Wrap command with "" if spaces are present to treat as $2
# Wraping time only nessisay for pros ;-) $3
# Example synax;
# format_space_do_time "/dir with/sp ac e s" "Comand With options" "TimeToSleep"
# Set $1, $2 and $3 variable names such that they can be hard-coded for debugging
File_Path="$1"
Commands="$2"
Timed_Sleep="$3"
format_space_do_time (){
# Check if services or command is already in proggress
while true
do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "$Commands" > /dev/null
    then
    # Waite $Time_Sleep for $Commands to finish
    sleep $Time_Sleep;
    else
    # $Commands not detected. Start'em now
    for i in "$File_Path/"*
    do
        # Magic time, lets deal with spaces in $i and save it to $entry
        # Option 1 replaces " " with "$'\0'" which is bashs way of dealing with spaces
        entry1=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/ /$\'\\\0\'/g')
        # Option 2 can be used to replace " " with "\ " of cource without the quotes around them :-)
        entry2=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/ /\\\ /g')
        # Clear previous outputs
        clear
        # run $Commands against $entry1
        # Change 1 to 2 for the other option
        ${Commands} "${entry1}" > /dev/null
    done
    fi
done
}
```

The above scirpt was addapted from the following link

http://www.cenolan.com/2013/03/looping-video-playlist-omxplayer-raspberry-pi/

They had something that worked fine until I had to deal with a Gatesbox user's hard drive. I personally use this script for playing music and movies via the command line. For example I save the above as omx_play_lister.sh then `chmod +x omx_play_lister` and run with;

```
./omx_play_lister "/media/mount/cWin/Music by artist/artist name and album folder" "omxplayer -ohdmi --vol=-2500" "5"
```

Which will happily take the file path; `/media/mount/cWin/Music by artist/artist name and album folder` and convert to `/media/mount/cWin/Music\ by\ artist/artist\ name\ and\ album\ folder` or null bites in the case of omxplayer and ls and many others that don't much like "" around stuff when being passed file paths. Bonus of using the sed command within the look near the end is that even if the files themselves contain spaces those too are formatted out before being passed to the `$Commands`
The little `"${entry}"` and `"$File_Path/"*` where the trickiest bits of formatting to sort out but it works well for what I nead it for and likely with a little moddification will work for your usages too.

Happy hacking and modding all.